# How to make :after pseudo element responsive

Tags: css

I created a Wordpress site and I added a blockquote element in the about section of the homepage.

I used :before and :after to insert a qoute unicode in my blockquote element but the problem is the :after pseudo quote is not responsive.

I inserted a top: 45% right: 34% temporarily and it works only for min-width: 1200px screensize.

```
blockquote {
  display:block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 75px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  /*Font*/
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #242424;
}

blockquote::before{
  content: "\201C"; 
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFC107;

  /*Positioning*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -10px;
 }

blockquote::after{
  content: "\201D";
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFC107;

 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 right: 34%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "not responsive" ("responsive" isn't a very well-defined term...), but I assume you mean that the position of the inserted `::after` element is only correct at a specific window size?

The opening quotation mark always appears at the same position relative to the text, but the closing mark is positioned to the edge of the `<blockquote>` element, not the end of the text inside it.  At some window sizes, when the text wrapping leaves a large gap between the last word of the text and the edge of the element, the quotation mark is separated from the text.  This is made worse because of the large font size.

In your specific case, a simple solution is to change the `blockquote::after` selector to `blockquote p::after`, and remove the `top:45%` and `right:34%` properties.  The `::after` element is then inserted at the end of the text, which means its position changes as the text reflows.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for making it clear. What is the right method to center my blockquote element?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve a similar issue by just adding this:

```
width: inherit;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.